# Gcc optimization question: unsigned mod vs if branch

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, modulo

I have a function which is called in a real-time microcontroller program (ARM Cortex-M) very often (at least 40,000 times per second), and it basically keeps a counter inside the length of a buffer which is not a power of two.

So I can have one of these two options:

```
extern uint32_t x;

void increment_MOD(void)
{
    x = (x + 1) % 100;
}
```

or

```
void increment_IF(void)
{
    uint32_t tmp = x + 1;
    if (tmp >= 100)
        tmp = 0;
    x = tmp;
}
```

These two seem functionally equivalent unless I am wrong, so:

**Would it be incorrect for GCC to optimize one of them into the faster form (whichever one it is)?**

It looks like the "if" version would still be faster, unless pipeline/branch misprediction is a problem (but ARM Cortex-M cpus don't have large pipelines AFAIK).

```
// it's nice to see that % is implemented
// using multiplication and shifts

increment_MOD:
    ldr r1, .L2
    ldr r3, .L2+4
    ldr r2, [r1]
    add r2, r2, #1
    umull r0, r3, r2, r3
    lsr r3, r3, #5
    add r3, r3, r3, lsl #2
    add r3, r3, r3, lsl #2
    sub r3, r2, r3, lsl #2
    str r3, [r1]
    bx lr
.L2:
   .word x
   .word 1374389535

// this is the IF variant

increment_IF:
    ldr r2, .L6
    ldr r3, [r2]
    add r3, r3, #1
    cmp r3, #99
    movhi r3, #0
    str r3, [r2]
    bx lr
.L6:
    .word x
```

Comment: In theory this would be a valid optimization by the as-if rule but I would not expect that a compiler implements it.

Comment: Notice that you might add your own optimization pass to GCC with your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). But this takes a lot of efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimization is not valid as the compiler cannot know from the code given that `x` is never>99 when the function is entered. If the function is entered with `x=100`, then at the exit of the function `increment_IF` with the if branch `x=0`, while for the mod variant `increment_MOD` you get `x=1`.